# can we run react native cli app on physical device without Android studio

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

In the documentation of react native cli there is processe to run react native cli app directly on physical device but I am confused that do we need Android studio to run my physical device as emulator or I can directly run my physical phone as emulator by connecting through usb debugging and typing the command given there

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your phone via USB and turn on debugging mode.

You can check device connectivity via running the ADB command.

```
adb devices
```

if you see your device in the console then just simply run your application via

```
react-native-run-android
```

Comment: Do I need Android studio or not

Comment: No you don't. But you'll need the Android SDK installed